# Question about notation in First Variation Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don’t really understand the notation behind
$$
D_x\phi(t,x_0)=\left(\dfrac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x_j}(t;x_0)\right)
$$
in the text below:
[image]

Why did the write the subscript $x$ under $D$? So why do we have $D_x$ instead of just $D$? And why do they say “with respect to initial conditions”, instead of “evaluated at initial conditions”? Or is it even evaluated? Do they fix $t$ and then evaluate at all the possible $x_0$? I’m just confused.

Maybe if I understand this notation, I will be able to understand the statements in the theorem as well, which for now are very unclear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $x$ is indeed there to represent differentiation wrt. those variables and not $t$, the RHS of your first equation has indices $i,j$ varying from $1$ to $n$, so that you get the matrix of the derivative.

If the subindex $x$ weren't there, one could interpret that one needs to compute all derivatives of a function from $R^{1+n}$ into $R^n$. Also because the function $\phi (t;x_0)$ denotes the solution at time $t$ with initial condition $x_0$, the author speaks of differentiability wrt. them, meaning wrt. the value of $x_0$ (which is not fixed until you solve the system: each choice yields a different solution curve).

In other words: for fixed $x_0$, you can think of $\phi$ as a curve in $R^n$, parametrized by $t$ and if you vary $x_0$ in an neighborhood you get a family of curves which depends differentiably on the choice of starting point.